# Getting kubernetes pod upTime in springboot services

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have two Springboot service (serviceA, serviceB). I want getting serviceB pods uptime in serviceA. how should I do?

I try to create loadBalancer in my system with specific field. I try to getting upTime pods data with `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-loadbalancer` but didnot worked.

Comment: That sounds a little challenging, and probably requires using the Kubernetes API to find all of the matching Pods.  Why do you need this data at the application level?  Is monitoring it through your metrics system enough?

Comment: I want loadBalancing my input request. My system have many caches, when I load balance with this parameter my request response Time It will be great, and cache hite

Comment: I'm not totally clear how a load-balancing or caching-related concern would require one set of application Pods finding another set of Pods' startup times.  What's the high-level problem you're trying to solve?  (Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Maybe my question is not true. I need ServiceB pods uptime, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution but not with Kubernetes. I getting `getRuntimeMXBean` from `ManagementFactory` and works for me.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
class UptimeController {

    @GetMapping("/uptime")
    fun getUptime(): Long {
        val runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()
        return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(runtimeMXBean.uptime)
    }
}
```